# Fastest way to get pixel color in Python or C++?

Tags: c++, python, tkinter, pixel, blur

I'm trying to add a blur effect to a transparent Tkinter widget I'm making.

I made the widget partially transparent with this line (snippet)

```
self.attributes("-alpha", 0.85)
```

In order to add the effect I desire I need to get the RGB values of each individual pixel in the widget. Seeing as the widget is only partially opaque I can not use the **.cget** method because it returns it's fill RGB value (the color before it's made partially transparent), not it's actual RGB value).

I currently am using this function (snippet)

```
def get_pixel_colour(self, i_x, i_y):
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)
```

However, it is **far** too slow for my purposes. Is there any faster way to get pixel color?

**Edit:**

If Python is just too slow for this purpose, I can also use C++.
I just need to get the RGB values of pixels at different x, y coordinates.

Comment: This really sounds like something that's just going to be way too slow  when done in Python. Seems you've even introduced a nasty platform dependency there. And when it comes to realtime graphics, a `get_pixel_color` function is usually a bad idea anyways.

Comment: See Edit, also it only has to work in Windows

Comment: Oh, do you already have another platform dependency you just can't get around, then?

Comment: It's not that I can't get around it; It's just that I can't get around it with out a substantial modification to the code. So another bit that is platform dependent isn't a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to take a look at the Python Image Library you could call something like this

```
import Image
im = Image.open("name_of_file.jpg")
list_of_pixels = list(im.getdata())
print list_of_pixels[0]
```

That would output the very first pixel in a RGB format like (255,255,255)
It is pretty fast but it wont ever beat C++ I believe